# List has no rows for assignment to Sobject - Why is SF returning an error instead of returning null?

Tags: apex

```
Account acc = [Select id,Name from Account where Name='Hypothetical124'];
System.debug(acc);
```

Why is this statement returning an error and not null ? 
I know the work around of making the assignment to a List just to get around this problem.
Any thoughts on why this was designed this way?

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is that they wanted the reasons for using the `SObject o = [SELECT ...];` syntax vs. the `List<SObject> o = [SELECT ...];` to be about how well you know your data.

The `SObject o = [SELECT ...];` should be used syntax when you know there to be one result, and only one result and that anything else is an error.

The `List<SObject> o = [SELECT ...];` syntax should be used when you don't know how many results will be returned, there could be 0, 1 or many.

SFDC could have quite easily designed the API so that the `SObject o = [SELECT ...];` syntax returned `null` when there were no results instead, in which case you would use it in situations where you expect there to be only 0 or 1 results.

However, they did not. I expect this is because situations where there should only ever be one result - and the absence that of result is an error - occur more frequently than those where there can only be 0 or 1 results.

To get the behaviour you can either use the `LIMIT` keyword to ensure there is only 0 or 1 results to a list query, or you can catch and ignore the exception.

Here are some examples:

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Hypothetical124' LIMIT 1];
Account acc = !accs.isEmpty() ? accs[0] : null;
```

Or:

```
Account acc = null;

try {
    acc = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Hypothetical124'];
} catch(QueryException e) {
    // Do nothing, carry on
}
```

Comment: @shaliniMendu to add to this, SFDC wants developers to always think in terms of bulk actions as subsequent DML from SOQL should be 'bulked'. As best practice blogs / books such as Salesforce Enterprise Design Patterns reinforce over an d over again, do all your operations as lists and maps